# Can `gpg --symmetric` produce reproducible output?

Tags: linux, encryption, gnupg

Out of curiosity, I would like to know if it possible to use `gpg --symmetric` in a way that encrypting the same data with the same password (and algorithms) will generate the same output each time.

I have run the following test and concluded that encrypting the same `input` file twice results in different output files:

```
$ head -c 100 /dev/urandom > input
$ gpg --symmetric --batch --passphrase test --yes -z0- -o out1.gpg input
$ gpg --symmetric --batch --passphrase test --yes -z0- -o out2.gpg input

$ sha1sum out1.gpg out2.gpg 
6047556b23549dfd6fc3c8766f7d2f00e60d1e4f  out1.gpg
1ad91b8937dc1718998291e76b501e643c6d452a  out2.gpg
```

I have used `-z0` since I know compression could be one of the factors to alter the output. From `man gpg` "a value of 0 for n disables compression."

Are there other flags that would be necessary to obtain reproducible output? Or it this not an option at all?

For completeness, if this is possible, why could it be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes, in practice the program isn't designed to allow for that.

First, because this is using the OpenPGP format, and OpenPGP is designed around *hybrid* encryption (user RSA keys encrypt a session key), it still follows the same architecture even in symmetric mode – your passphrase doesn't encrypt the data directly; it only encrypts a "session key" packet, and that session key is of course randomly generated. In theory it would be possible for you to pre-generate that session key and provide it from a file, but GnuPG doesn't have an option for that.

Another source of non-reproduceability is a salt used for the KDF (i.e. the "hash algorithm" used to convert your passphrase to the actual encryption key). Again, usually it's deliberately random.

Final factor, which applies to any encryption software, is an *IV* used for nearly all cipher modes; the purpose of an IV is to make sure the cipher starts in a reasonably unique state. (For some cipher modes 'unique' is rather critical¹; for others somewhat less so.)

It is *possible* to have reproducible cipher output with a "synthetic IV" which is based on some form of a hash of the clear-text (so that different inputs will still provide a unique IV, but the same input gets the same IV). However, that's something that GnuPG itself would need to do internally, and I don't think it currently has such an option. (For example, one downside of a synthetic IV is that the program must buffer the whole input to compute the IV before it can be encrypted, whereas a random IV allows data to be directly streamed.)

---

¹ (When encrypting different inputs with the same key. If the *same* input is encrypted again, a non-unique IV merely reveals "this is definitely the same input", but when *different* inputs are used with the same key & IV, this could range from bad to disastrous, e.g. leaking the actual key.)